# What is the opcode of the BLX instruction?

Tags: arm

Whats the opcode for the BLX instruction in ARM Assembly ? and the size.
In windows the JMP opcode is 0xE9
How do I find the opcode and the size for the BLX instruction

Comment: Look at the ARM Architecture Reference Manual (ARM ARM) for encoding. In ARM architecture BLX instruction can be 2 bytes or 4 bytes depending on if it is Thumb-2 or ARM instruction set.

Comment: I'm looking for the one in ARM instruction set